# Create Domain that have valid format and skip others

Tags: php, laravel, format

I am working on storing functionality of domains in laravel 5.3. Here user enter multiple domains in textarea one per line I want to validate each domain with right format should be create and other should be skipped and also count with correct format and bad format.
here is my code

```
$name = $request->input('domain_name');
$domains = preg_split('/[\r\n ,]+/', $name);

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $data['domain'] = $domain;
    $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    if (empty($request->input('domain_id'))) {
        $domain = Domain::create($data);
    }
}
```

Domain name with correct format should create and skip bad format and count both correct and incorrect formats.
Thanks for Help

Comment: *one per line* --> can [split the entire text blob](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) by the definition of line separator like.. \n (or \n\r on Windows, perhaps). then match each of them with your validation.

Comment: @BagusTesa how to validate it?

Comment: look at the answer, someone already answered for you :) but remember to split the list of domains first.

Comment: yes i am splitting already if you have look on my question @BagusTesa

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match` and `Regex`:

```
if( ! preg_match("/^(?!-)(?:[a-zA-Zd-]{0,62}[a-zA-Zd].){1,126}(?!d+)[a-zA-Zd]{1,63}$/", $domain)) continue; // skip
```

or you can use this :

```
if(filter_var(gethostbyname($domain), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
    return 'True';
}
```

Comment: it gives error as  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found @bara' ayyash

Comment: thanks its validating but i also keep continue but not create bad once and calculate both good and bad formats domains

Comment: i have added another way

Comment: you not updating about how calculate number of domains with true and false format

Comment: you can just create a `$counter` and when you make `continue`, increment the counter. the counter will have number of invalid domains, and then subtract the list length with the counter, you will have number of valid domains !